get correct culture Resource string from viewModel injecting context in kotlin jetpack compose
I'm trying to get the resource string from viewmodels and use cases, i have six string translate resources files but i always got the default string translations, isn't getting the established culture
My interface
interface ResourceController {
    fun getString(resourceId: Int): String
}

My implementation
class ResourceControllerImpl @Inject constructor(private val context: Context
) : ResourceController {
    override fun getString(resourceId: Int): String {
        return context.getString(resourceId)
    }
}

My module injection

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ConfigModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun resourceControllerProvider(@ApplicationContext context: Context): ResourceController {
        return ResourceControllerImpl(context)
    }
}

My useCase
class GetTemplateToPrint @Inject constructor(
    private val resourceController: ResourceController,
    private val deviceUtils: DeviceUtils
    ) {
    fun invoke(): String {
        var dataToPrint : String = ""
        val terminal = deviceUtils.getDeviceSerialNumber() ?: deviceUtils.getDeviceId()
        dataToPrint = "${getString(R.string.serial_number_label)}:| $terminal"
        return dataToPrint
    }

    private fun getString(resId: Int): String {
        return resourceController.getString(resId)
    }
}


R.string.serial_number_label exist in six resource string files (es, en, fr, it, de, ca)
but it's always returning the default resource string
have anyone how can i do it? thanks :)

Make sure the resource configuration is correct not misspelled. Can you show the folder structure for your resources. Also, did you try changing the device language. Also, other reason could be how are you calling the invoke()of use-case. ViewModel can survive config changes and maybe you are calling use-case invoke on init of VM. The best approach should passing down the StringRes and the dataToPrint to activity from you Viewmodel.

The configuration is correct because I have multiples composable screens using, for example: stringResource(id = R.string.serial_number_label) and it's work fine when i change the application language in my configuration screen, but when i want to get the resource throught the injected getString useCase, i always get the default translation
